# Multiple refercences to same table RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, model, foreign-keys

I have two models, User and Peticion. I want Peticion to save two references to two different Users, that is to say, two User's ids. Here's the migration to create Peticion model

```
class CreatePeticionExtras < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :peticion_extras do |t|
      t.references :user_solicitante, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user_solicitado, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Peticion's model

```
class PeticionExtra < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :solicitante, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :solicitado, class_name: "User"
end
```

And User's model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :solicitudes, class_name: "PeticionExtra", foreign_key: "user_solicitado_id", dependent: :destroy
  has_many :peticiones, class_name: "PeticionExtra", foreign_key: "user_solicitante_id", dependent: :destroy
```

The problem is that when I call Peticion's create on the controller

```
def create
    peticion_extra = PeticionExtra.new(user_solicitante_id: params[:peticionextra][:user_solicitante_id], user_solicitado_id: params[:peticionextra][:user_solicitado_id])
respond_to do |format|
      if peticion_extra.save
        flash[:success] = "Petición enviada"
        format.html {redirect_to ejercicios_path and return}
        format.json {redirect_to ejercicios_url and return}
      else
        format.html {render action: "new"}
        format.json {render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity}
      end
    end
  end
```

It throws an error: "SQLite3::SQLException at /peticion_extra/crear
no such table: main.user_solicitados" in the line `if peticion_extra.save`

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you can't have two different relations called `:user` like you propose

```
class PeticionExtra < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_solicitante_id"
  belongs_to :user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "user_solicitado_id"
end
```

Try to answer a question what should be returned if you do

```
PetitionExtra.last.user
```

Should it return `solicitado` or `solicitante`?

try with:

```
class PeticionExtra < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :solicitante, class_name: "User"
  belongs_to :solicitado, class_name: "User"
end
```

I don't see any other obvious problems with your code...

Answer (score 0):

The proble was in the migration. It kept looking for user_solicitante and user_solicitado tables as I stablished `foreign_key: true`. I solved it changing the migration like this:

```
class CreatePeticionExtras < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :peticion_extras do |t|
      t.references :user_solicitante, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.references :user_solicitado, foreign_key: { to_table: :users }
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```